# C# DefaultAzureCredentials + Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, .net-6.0, azure-identity, defaultazurecredential

Right now I'm converting our apps from connecting to Azure App Configs and Azure Key Vaults using Client IDs + Secrets to using the DefaultAzureCredentials.  Overall, I like the additional security that I'm gaining.  And that I can govern access via a combination of Azure AD Groups (Developers) and Managed Identities (Deployed Apps).

One big issue I'm running into is using the Interactive Browser Credential adds about 10 seconds to the startup time of the app.  Plus developers have to manually click on their account in the browser before the app even continues launching.  Is there a way to have the DefaultAzureCredentials use the Visual Studio account instead of having to go to the browser?  Or is there any other way to improve startup speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work with your `Visual Studio Account`. You need to log in with your `Azure Ad Account`.

You can do this with the [`Azure Service Authentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#authenticate-via-visual-studio) from Visual Studio or with the Azure Cli `az login`.

`AzureDefaultCredentials` try different authentication methods in a specific order which you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential).

Comment: Aah thanks.  That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Curtis please mark the answer as the answer so that it doesn't pollute the `unanswered` filter.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Thanks for the reminder.